# Getting the error: "TypeError: implement_array_function expected 6 arguments, got 5"

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I had tried installing a new package, but something seems to have been messed up.

When I try running this line of code:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
```

it returns the error:

`TypeError: implement_array_function expected 6 arguments, got 5`

I'm not sure why it's not working properly. I tried updating the package, but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments by `Tim Roberts`, it appears that `NumPy` wasn't updated to the latest version, which caused the problem. Updating it seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Is your `numpy` out of date?  This seems to be a conflict between `scipy` and `numpy`.

Comment: It's the latest version of ```numpy```, perhaps ```scipy``` isn't updated yet to work with the latest version of ```numpy```? I'll try seeing if an earlier version works.

Comment: It seemed that ```NumPy``` actually wasn't updated. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy) is an important dependency of
[scipy](https://pypi.org/project/scipy).
Packages list ranges of "compatible" versions for their dependencies,
but it's not always feasible to test all combinations
so incompatible combos might slip past `pip`.

Update to modern versions of both libraries.
For example:

- scipy 1.11.1 relying upon
- numpy 1.23.5

---

In general, when you upgrade an existing or install a new library,
take the opportunity to upgrade the rest of your project.
Then run your
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
to verify everyone is still playing nicely together.
Roll back the versions if not.

You *do* have a test suite, right?
If not, go write a small one which minimally verifies
that  all your `import`s succeed.
It will be the canary in a coal mine during future version upgrades.